# React Enzyme Test - DOM manipulation with componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, mount

I am manipulating the DOM with `componentDidMount` based on element positions. It works perfectly in React, but I would like to create an unit test for that.

Basically, I have a container with a bunch of children elements and I want to add a class for children that are wrapped (not in the first row). I do that logic in `componentDidMount`.

**How can I test with enzyme unit tests?**

I thought to use `mount` but it does not result. Any idea?

```
class Container extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    this.updateChildren()
  }

  updateChildren () {
    // logic to add a class if element position is different than 1st line
    // calls render again with state update
  }

  ...
}
```

Unit test:

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import Container from '../Container'

describe('<Container />', () => {
 it('renders and hides second row elements'), () => {
   const container = mount(
   <div style={{ width: 200 }}>
      <Container> ...childrens </Container>
   </div>
   )

   expect(wrapper.render()).toMatchSnapshot()
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

ComponentDidMount is just like a method in your class.

So, you can directly call the method in your unit test this way

```
wrapper = shallow(<Your Component />);

// call the method
wrapper.instance().componentDidMount()
```

You can write a mock implementation for that method if you need.